# Nancy ASP.NET Hosting vs. OWIN Hosting

Tags: asp.net, owin, nancy

I am working on a Nancy project and it comes with an ASP.NET hosting reference `Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet`. What is the difference between this and other `OWIN` hosting options ?